# Connecting Spark to HAWQ via JDBC driver

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hawq

Trying to connect to HAWQ from Spark, using greenplum's odbc/jdbc drivers (downloaded from the proper Pivotal page).

Using Spark 1.4, here's the sample code written in python:
(All capitals have proper variable assignments)
...

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext


sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.load(source='jdbc',\
                      url='IP_ADDRESS:PORT/DB_NAME?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD&ssl=true',\
                      dbtable='SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME')
```

...

Spark submit command appends the odbc driver to the classpath. I've done a 'hello world' with the basic sqlContext instantiation and everything runs fine on the cluster. But when I try to actually connect to the HAWQ postgresql db it will not run.

Error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o24.load.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: path
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.CaseInsensitiveMap.default(ddl.scala:467)
        at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.CaseInsensitiveMap.apply(ddl.scala:467)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any thoughts or suggestions? I've tried at least 20 combinations of the "df = sqlContext.read.load..." definition but to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct format for JDBC should be something like this

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:postgresql://node1:5432/postgres?user=myuser&password=password',dbtable='test').load()
```

Another example here
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved the issue. I tried many, many JDBC drivers, the one that worked was postgresql-9.4-1202.jdbc4.jar which is available from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html (NOTE: Pivotal's greenplum.tar driver also worked). My final spark-submit CL command was as follows: ./spark-submit --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=PATH_TO_DRIVER/postgresql.tar --driver-class-path PATH_TO_DRIVER/postgresql.tar PATH_TO_PYAPP/pyapp.py  ...ALSO, had to install the driver in the same directory path on the HAWQ master node as the Spark master node